# Get a total from one table referencing ids from another

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I need to get a total on one of my tables (Loans) which has multiple 'UserIDs' with the same id, so a user can get more than one book but alsmo means they can have multiple fines for different books (Pictured below)
[image]

I want to list every user, and then list the total fine they owe but I cant figure out how.

Heres my PATRON(User) database aswell for referrence
[image]

I have got all the users and books used and I'm not sure how I can do something similar with the next objective

```
SELECT PATRON.Name, BOOK.CallNo, BOOK.Title, BOOK.Subject
FROM (BOOK INNER JOIN LOAN ON BOOK.CallNo = LOAN.CallNo) INNER JOIN PATRON ON LOAN.UserID = PATRON.USerID;
```

Comment: The parentheses in the `join` clause suggest MS Access, but you should tag the question clearly based on the database you are really using.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I want to use a similar MySQL statement than the one I listed at the end that works for my next objective but I cant ifgure it out, I dont know what you mean by what youre saying, I am pretty in experienced in SQL statements and even less knowledge in access

Comment: . . You have tagged the question with two databases:  MySQL and MS Access. It is unlikely you are using both.  Remove one of the tags.

Comment: I am using MySQL statements and primarily learning that, but for this exersize I am using Access

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT PATRON.Name,
       BOOK.CallNo,
       BOOK.Title,
       BOOK.Subject,
       SUM(LOAN.Fine) AS TotalFine
FROM BOOK,
     LOAN,
     PATRON
WHERE BOOK.CallNo = LOAN.CallNo
  AND LOAN.UserID = PATRON.USerID
GROUP BY PATRON.USerID;
```

Comment: This (I dont think) is quite what I meant

Comment: I meant I want to list every user and the total fine they owe, this (from the looks of it) just gets the book and the loan that might be owed, or the total owed (although these would be the same number, no?)

Comment: Let me get this straight, you want to get the total fine of a specific user and display their Name, CallNo, Title (of the book), Subject (of the book), and TotalFine?

Comment: yeah, so itll display every user once, and then about 3-4 of them will have a total fine (although, one has multiple fines) and itll just show the totoal once

Comment: @Cacoon did you run that query? that's exactly this query does afaik

Comment: @Cacoon okay, i have amended the query. I can't test it out on my computer, so pardon my syntax errors

Comment: from the looks of it, it should work but it doesnt want to accept it for some reaosn, thanks for the help though

Comment: @Cacoon you are welcome. if you get more errors, do show me a screen shot of it so i can analyse it further

Answer (score 0):

Well, one can only guess what kind of data is in the other two tables since you didn't give us a screen shot of them, so I'll give the most basic answer and work out from there.

> I want to list every user, and then list the total fine they owe

```
SELECT LOAN.UserID, 
       Sum(LOAN.Fine) AS SumOfFine
FROM LOAN
GROUP BY LOAN.UserID;
```

From there, if you need information from a `PATRON` table (assuming it stores `UserID`), you can do an `INNER JOIN`, it would look like:

```
SELECT LOAN.UserID, 
       Sum(LOAN.Fine) AS SumOfFine,
       PATRON.[Name],
       PATRON.Age
FROM LOAN
     INNER JOIN PATRON
     ON LOAN.UserID = PATRON.UserID
GROUP BY LOAN.UserID, PATRON.[Name], Patron.Age;
```

I'm unsure of how the `BOOK` table is set up.